# how many maximum session of a particular browser can be opened using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
i am trying doing automation using selenium......i have opened a hub by 
`start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar -role hub -port 6156`
and then started a node on a fifefox browser by 
`start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar -role node -hub
http://localhost:6156/grid/register -browser                                                                                                                                 "browserName=firefox,setjavascriptEnabled=true,acceptSslCerts=true,maxInstances=5,platform=WINDOWS" -port 6157`
```

here i mentioned maxInstances=5, if i change it to 10 then also at one instance only 5 browser is opening.......can anybody suggest that is it a restriction in selenium that at one instance we can have only maxium 5 instance of a particular browser opening......how many maxium session of firefox can i open at one time.

Answer (score 1):

Set the '-maxSession' property. This property represents how many browsers can be run simultaneously in a node.

'maxInstances' sets how many instances of a particular browser can opened where as 'maxSession' decides how many total browsers (includes all firefox,ie, chrome etc.) can be run in a node.

Comment: can you please suggest that how many maximum sessions of a particular browser(firefox) can be launched simultaneosly, and what is the command for it and we need to mention it in hub command or node or both??

Comment: I dont know how many sessions of a particular browser you can set in grid. I suppose the session depends upon the jettyThreads which is set to 255. The support for browser and session depends upon the system memory and cpu. I had invoked closed to 40 simultaneous sessions on a i5 processor and a 16gb ram machine. You may need to do a hit and run on your server or systems for this.